# How to specify Content-type when using Recess framework with Smarty

Tags: php, http, http-headers, smarty, recess

I am currently using the PHP Recess framework with the Smarty templating engine. In my controller, I have code similar to:

```
/**
* !View Smarty
* !RespondsWith Smarty
* !Prefix Views: templates/, Routes: /
*/

class XHomeController extends Controller {

    /** !Route GET */
    function index()
    {
            $this->title = "Some title...";
    }

}
```

and, in the corresponding Smarty view, I refer to `{$title}` as usual.

The view renders correctly in all browsers except Android browsers (on my 2.3 Nexus One, on a 3.2 tablet as well as in the Android emulator). I think that I've traced the problem to the fact that the Smarty view is being rendered and sent to the browsers without a Content-type.

Using http://web-sniffer.net/, I notice that Content-type in the Response is empty.

How can I specify the Content-type in Recess when using Smarty? I've tried adding header('Content-type: text/html') to the method in the controller but this does not work.

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to see the SmartyView code in recess/framework/views. That class should have a canRespondWith() method that will verify if a view can respond with a certain MIMEType. For example:

```
class XmlView extends AbstractView {

    public function canRespondWith(Response $response) {
            return 'xml' === $response->request->accepts->format();
    }
}
```

If this returns true, then the XmlView will be used. In the AbstractView class, the sendHeaders() method will set the Content-Type:

```
protected function sendHeadersFor(Response $response) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 ' . ResponseCodes::getMessageForCode($response->code));

    $format = $response->request->accepts->format();
    header('Content-Type: ' . MimeTypes::preferredMimeTypeFor($format));
    /* ... */
}
```

Look in recess/http/MimeTypes.class.php to see how 'xml' will respond with the correct headers. You also need to look in your SmartyView to see what mimetype you are returning to see what header will be set.